# What type of exercises should a person do if he/she is suffering from osteoporosis?

Tags: exercise, bones, stretching, physical-therapy, osteoporosis

Is there a possibility that somebody could tell me specifically an exercise plan or a source where I can get authentic information on exercises for senior people suffering from diseases related to bones and muscles and can it include all types of exercises related to aerobic, anaerobic, strength training, calisthenics, stretching exercises, specialized training, physical therapy, pilates and yoga.

Answer (score 1):

[Source](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/exercise-benefits-for-osteoporosis-reduces-bone-fracture-risk/)

Osteoporosis exercises are encouraged for a number of reasons. First and foremost exercise is good in a general sense, but building muscle strength can be really beneficial to people who may be at risk of losing bone mass. 
Stronger muscles can help improve balance, which can prevent falls.

Balancing exercises are therefore a good addition to any workout routine. Regular exercise that includes muscle strength or resistance training, as well as weight-bearing aerobic activity can help prevent bone loss, as we get older.

You don’t have to get overly aggressive, especially if you have already had a fall and are nervous about exercise. Nonimpact activities such as balance and posture exercises can benefit people with osteoporosis even though they don’t build bone density. These non-impact approaches can still increase muscle strength and decrease your risk of falling and potentially breaking bones.

If you are at risk of osteoporosis or you have already been diagnosed with osteoporosis, most doctors agree that supervised weight-bearing exercise is the safest.

**Exercises which strengthen bones and reduce fractures risk**

Exercises which strengthen bones and reduce fractures risk If you want to experience the benefits of exercise and reduce fracture risk there are four different areas you should consider.

**Strength training** – This area of exercise focuses on free weights, such as dumbbells, weight machines or exercise bands. They can make muscles and bones work by lifting, pushing and pulling.

**Balance training** – These exercises reduce your base of support. For example, instead of standing on two legs, you stand on one. Challenging your balance can actually strengthen your balance.

**Posture training** – This involves paying attention to how different parts of your body are aligned. The alignment of the spine can become a concern for people with osteoporosis.

**Weight bearing aerobic activity** – This can be rhythmic activity that you do for at least 10 minutes at a time. Jumping rope, tennis or dancing are good examples.

Yoga and Pilates are two very popular forms of exercise today. They can improve strength, balance and flexibility. While they may sound enticing, certain positions may not be safe for people with osteoporosis. As an example, movements that require you to bend forward could increase your chance of breaking a bone in your spine.

Here are some of the exercises that fall into the above categories and that osteoporosis sufferers say they have had success with.

- Functional movements, such as standing and rising up on toes
- Doing low-impact aerobics
- Using stair-step machines
- Fast walking on a treadmill
- Hiking
- Dancing
- Tai Chi

Comment: is this answer a paraphrase of the source or quotes from it?